# Set Docker Container Iptable Rules

Tags: docker, containers, iptables, podman

I have a linux server that kicks off a variety of docker containers on boot. I'd like to implement firewall rules for those containers specific to the container. The containers are connecting to servers with known static ips and ports. I've considered creating the rules inside the container's network namespace using netns to add rules but the namespace is being created via CNI and I would like the rules to be implemented when the namespace gets created, rather than configure the firewall of an already created container.

Most of what I can find about setting up iptables via CNI seems to refer to configuring the host firewall. Does Docker have some way of defining container specific firewall rules that get implemented when a container is run? I'd prefer to not use 3rd party products to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I had made a tool a year ago for the same reason. There is no documentation but if you run it with -h you will get a good indication of how it works. You can use it as a service on Linux with a configuration file and your rules in yaml. I hope it is still up to date with the docker api (I just made it public). You can look at the code, it's pretty simple.

here: https://github.com/tr4cks/docker-netns

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31163937)